# How to combine 4 bytes and do math calculation in C using AVR

Tags: arrays, byte, formula, long-integer, avr

I have an atMega1281 micro controller using C. I have a routine to pull 4 bytes off of a CAN bus to read an SPN. I am able to get the 4 bytes but I cannot print the 4 byte number because it is truncating the the first 2 bytes making it a 16 bit number. I have tried using unsigned long as the declaration with no success. What is the trick when using 32 bit numbers with an AVR?

```
unsigned long engine_hours_raw;
float engine_hours_uint;

engine_hours_raw =  (OneMessage.Msg.Data[3] << 24) | (OneMessage.Msg.Data[2] << 16) | (OneMessage.Msg.Data[1] << 8) | OneMessage.Msg.Data[0]);
engine_hours_uint = engine_hours_raw * 0.05;

ftoa(engine_hours_uint, engHours, 1);
UART1_Printf("Engine Hours: %s   ", engHours);
```

Comment: Just to be sure: how are you printing the 4 bytes number?

Comment: I actually convert the float to a string using ftoa and then print as a string.

Comment: @Eddie On the bare metal embedded systems it not needed to stick to the standard as we know that the pointer is an actual address in the memory :)

Comment: "unsigned long"? For goodness sake, do use `uint32_t` for an unsigned 32bit integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(OneMessage.Msg.Data[3] << 24)` will be 0 as the default size for an expression is an int. unless it is cast.

Instead, load the data into the long int and then perform the shift.

```
engine_hours_raw = OneMessage.Msg.Data[3];
engine_hours_raw <<= 8;
engine_hours_raw |= OneMessage.Msg.Data[2];
engine_hours_raw <<= 8;
engine_hours_raw |= OneMessage.Msg.Data[1];
engine_hours_raw <<= 8;
engine_hours_raw |= OneMessage.Msg.Data[0];
```

You could also cast the intermediate expressions as unsigned log or uint32_t, but it just as messy and may take longer.

```
engine_hours_raw =  ((unit32_t)(OneMessage.Msg.Data[3]) << 24) | ((unit32_t)(OneMessage.Msg.Data[2]) << 16) | ((unit32_t)(OneMessage.Msg.Data[1]) << 8) | (unit32_t)(OneMessage.Msg.Data[0]);
```

Comment: why to complicate it ? we are in the bare metal embedded world. pointers and addresses are well known :)

Comment: This solution worked. I found a document explaining more detail about declarations. Thanks UncleO!

Answer (score 0):

There is much easier and straightforward way :)

```
uint32_t *engine_hours_raw = (uint32_t *)OneMessage.Msg.Data;
float engine_hours_uint  = *engine_hours_raw * 0.05;
```